# Semantic UI Complete Class List/Documentation

Tags: jquery, css, html, frameworks, semantic-ui

Does comprehensive documentation exist somewhere regarding the classes and modules available within Semantic-UI?

Or is the intent actually to drive traffic to their website any time you're unsure?
If so, that will eliminate it as a contender for this business.

Comment: You mean other than the list on the left side of their website? https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

Comment: I mean I thought that I said:
"Or is the intent actually to drive traffic to their website any time you're unsure? If so, that will eliminate it as a contender for this business."

Comment: What exactly is the point of your question?

Comment: I am looking for a comprehensive, downloadable User guide/documentation detailing the usage of Semantic-UI.

The project is to build out some intranet templates for use within a company where not everybody has external internet access.

Comment: So you want a downloadable documentation for offline usage. I'm not familiar with the framework they are using for docs but you could try out their git repo: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Docs